# Can't stop taking input and get the flow inside while loop?

Tags: c++

I am trying to implement Linked list in c++ and cannot seem to get that why I can't stop taking input from the terminal.

```
Node* take_input_better() {
int data;
cin >> data;
Node *head = NULL;
Node *tail = NULL;
while(data != -1) {
    cout << "debug" << endl;
    Node *newNode = new Node(data);
    if(head == NULL) {
        head = newNode;
        tail = newNode;
    }
    else {
        tail -> next = newNode;
        tail = tail -> next;
        // OR
        // tail = newNode;
    }
    cout << "Debug" << endl;
    cin >> data;
}
return head;
}
```

This function just creates a linked list with the element until -1 is entered.
If I enter the first element as -1. it seems to work fine. But when it is not -1 after I have already entered some data the program seem to take infinite number of inputs and the flow isn't even inside the while statement as the words "debug" and "Debug" don't get printed.

Edit 1: Here's the Full Program

Node.cpp

```
class Node {
public:
    int data;
    Node *next;

    Node(int data){
        this->data = data;
        next = NULL;
    }
};
```

linked_list.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include "Node.cpp"

Node* take_input_better() {
   int data;
   cin >> data;
   Node *head = NULL;
   Node *tail = NULL;
   while(data != -1) {
    cout << "debug" << endl;
    Node *newNode = new Node(data);
    if(head == NULL) {
        head = newNode;
        tail = newNode;
    }
    else {
        tail -> next = newNode;
        tail = tail -> next;
        // OR
        // tail = newNode;
    }
    cout << "Debug" << endl;
    cin >> data;
}
return head;
}

int length(Node *head){
  Node *temp = head;
  int count = 0;
  while(temp != NULL){
        count++;
  }
  return count;
}

int main(){
Node *head = take_input_better();
cout << "Length of the Linked List: " << length(head) << endl;
}
```

Comment: Seems to me that the problem will be in the code that calls this method, not in this method itself. It's always better to post a complete program, newbies are often mistaken in where they think the real problem is.

Comment: hmm i dont see any problem here. im suspecting that perhaps you have another cin within the Node constructor call. or one of the functions called within the node constructor call. it could well be that you endup getting stuck on an infinite loop within one of those inner cin calls thats not showing up in the example provided above.

Comment: I will edit to post the full code but there isn't any other cin in my program.

Answer (score 1):

The error is in the `length` function. You are not moving the `temp` pointer forward. Do this:

```
int length(Node *head){
  Node *temp = head;
  int count = 0;
  while(temp != NULL){
        count++;
        temp = temp->next;
  }
  return count;
}
```

Get familiar with the debugger. It is your friend.

Comment: Damn. just figured that out myself. Really noob.
How to use debugger in c++? I user terminal gcc;

Comment: From the terminal the gcc debugger is called gdb. But really using a debugger from the command line is hard work. You should find an IDE to use.

Answer (score -1):

You also need to make sure the input stream is in a readable state (e.g. `cin.good()`). If it goes into a fail state, `cin >> data` will keep going, but without waiting for new user input or putting any meaningful value into `data`.

Comment: How will I do that? Haven't ever same across this kind of problem.

Comment: But nothing in the OPs question indicates that they are entering invalid input

Comment: Nor would the symptom of not printing "Debug" be true if this was the real cause of the problem.

Comment: @user463035818 Not working still behaving the same way

Comment: I am entering only integer values.